# Pending transactions occur frequently

Tags: transactions

Recently consecutive transactions are pending.
For example, the following transaction.
I wait a few days for one transaction.
What do you think is the cause?
Thank you.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd51c2e576d5c045c1610c8fd1f31dcb5783cab764f1966c12901ac0e99bf1c81
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3d849e2f60c83b9e42e65e3557c01b85036d06495129419d9b45f53e25d4cf34
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x86e26f21f6fc3454ff6cb2c0a659a7c579d99298841d0fec03472e2f5c4a6c72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked three transactions and checked that those are taking long to be confirmed. The first transaction is not confirmed yet.

If the transaction is not confirmed soon, I think there are two reasons.

1. The chain's base gas fee is higher than Max Fee per gas.
2. The previous transaction which has the lower nonce is not confirmed because of reason 1.

And seems like your transaction's problem is the reason 1.
Recently, there are so many actions in Ethereum chain so that the base gas fee is normal higher than 25 gwei. But your transactions' Max Fee Per Gas is only 16.96978376 gwei. So that your transactions will not be confirmed until the base gas fee of the chain is lower than 16.96978376 gwei.

I can see that all the three transactions have the same Max Fee Per Gas. Seems like you are using bot or press "Send" Button on Wallet too fast (because wallets need time to get the Max Fee Per Gas).
So, please send transactions with high Max Fee Per Gas so that your transactions can be confirmed instantly.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd51c2e576d5c045c1610c8fd1f31dcb5783cab764f1966c12901ac0e99bf1c81 is still on pending. To solve this problem, please send the same transaction which has same nonce with high Max Fee Per Gas. Then, the transaction will be replaced with new transaction.

Thank you.

Comment: is correct in this context

Comment: Your precise answer helped me to understand the cause.
I will try to run it during the time when gas is cheaper. 
Thank you very much.