# Unable to resolve pending transactions

Tags: transactions

I asked the following questions and thought the issue of pending transactions was resolved.

[Pending transactions occur frequently](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145331/pending-transactions-occur-frequently)

However, it seems that neither speed up, cancellation, nor nonce replacement is effective, perhaps because speed up was already performed once and the transaction in question was not reflected.

I used the following article as a reference.

https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015489251-How-to-speed-up-or-cancel-a-pending-transaction

Why are all these transactions invalid and how can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You can try changing RPC. Looking at ethscan, the issue is that the lowest nonce tx is still underpriced. You need to make a new tx with that nonce and higher gas.

Comment: The answer in the previous question is the correct one. From the listing two are confirmed and the third transaction has been dropped. If them fail then it is likely an issue with the wallet. For metamask you could try reseting it, sometimes the nonce is saved locally and enter into conflicts if transactions are dropped or replaced.